# Permutation that produces permutations

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, permutations, integer-sequences

Let $f(n)$ be [A000045](https://oeis.org/A000045), i.e., Fibonacci numbers: $f(n)=f(n-1)+f(n-2)$ for $n>1$ with $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$.

Let $g(n)$ be [A072649](https://oeis.org/A072649), i.e., $n$ occurs $f(n)$ times. The sequence begins with
$$1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7$$

Let
$$h_0(n)=n-f(g(n)+1), h_0(0)=0$$
$$s(n,k)=f(g(n)+k)-n-1, s(0,k)=0$$
$$h_1(n)=s(s(n,2),3), h_1(0)=0$$

Let $t(n,k)$ be a sequence of the nonnegative integers such that $t(n,1)=n$ and for $k>1$ we take the binary representation of $k$ (with the most significant bit deleted) and apply $h_0(n)$ and $h_1(n)$ one to other in accordance with bits in the binary representation of $k$.

For example, $k=18$ in binary $10010$, then we have $t(n,18)=h_0(h_0(h_1(h_0(n))))$.

Let $a(n)$ be a permutaton of the nonnegative integers from the [one of my previous questions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/444050/permutation-and-its-binary-analog).

Let
$$b(n,m)=a(n)+b(t(n,m),m)-t(n,m), b(0,m)=0$$
I conjecture that $b(n,m)$ is permutation of the nonnegative integers for any $m>1, m\ne 2^k-1$.

Here is the PARI prog to verify this conjecture:

```
g(n)=if(n>0, my(A=0); until(fibonacci(A)>n, A++); A-2)
a(n) = if(n>0, my(A=g(n), B=n-fibonacci(g(n)+1), C=g(B-1)); n + if(B>0, - fibonacci(C) + if(A%2==C%2, fibonacci(A-2))))
h0(n) = if(n>0, n - fibonacci(g(n)+1))
s(n, k) = if(n>0, fibonacci(g(n)+k) - n - 1)
h1(n) = if(n>0, s(s(n, 2), 3))
t(n, k) = my(A=n); for(i=0, logint(k, 2) - 1, if(bittest(k, i), A=h1(A), A=h0(A))); A
b(n, m) = if(n>0, my(A=t(n, m)); a(n) + b(A, m) - A)
test(n, m) = my(A=0); while(!(b(A, m)==n), A++); A
```

Is there a way to prove it? Why it doesn't holds for $m=2^k-1$? Is there at least one another permutation of the nonnegative integers $c(n)$ (with at least one $k$ such that $c(k)\ne k$) such that if we change $a(n)$ to $c(n)$, then the resulting sequence $b(n,m)$ is also a permutation of the nonnegative integers for any $m>1, m\ne 2^k-1$?